# Value of Input field don''t change on button click

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

if i click on the buttons i see in the console that the value change but the value in the input field don't change so what did i wrong

JS

```js
let Eingabe = document.getElementById("eingabe").value;
let Eins = document.getElementById("ein");
let Zwei = document.getElementById("zwei");
let userinput = "";

console.log("bevor:", Eingabe);

Eins.addEventListener("click", function() {
  userinput = userinput + Eins.innerHTML
  Eingabe = userinput;
  console.log(Eingabe);
})

Zwei.addEventListener("click", function() {
  userinput = userinput + Zwei.innerHTML;
  Eingabe = userinput;
  console.log(Eingabe);

})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="eingabe" class="input" value="0">
<button id="ein" class="eins taste ">1</button>
<button id="zwei" class="zwei taste">2</button>
<button class="drei taste">3</button>
<button class="null taste">0</button>
<button class="gleich staste">=</button>
<button class="Del staste">DEL</button>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Assigning to `Eingabbe` doesn't assign to the value of the input.

Comment: Variables are not aliases. When you assign to `Engabbe`, you're copying the value out of the input, you're not making it a synonym for the input valiue.

Comment: This is a common beginner confusion. You need to read a tutorial on how variables and assignments work.